# Nginx не грузит static

Tags: django, nginx

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Nginx не грузит static

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 985205-ci41159.tmweb.ru www.985205-ci41159.tmweb.ru;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/mysite/myprojectdir/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что означает «не грузит»? Какой запрос, какой ответ, какой код ошибки, что написано в логах?

Comment: Ошибок нет, просто выгружает страницу без картинок и стилей.http://985205-ci41159.tmweb.ru/home/

Comment: Вот в браузерных инструментах разработчика и в мониторинге сети изучайте, куда там пропали картинки и стили

Comment: В частности в этом самом мониторинге сети видно, что на запросы стилей и картинок сервер отвечает ошибкой 403 — чем тонко намекает, что класть сайт в папку `/root/` было плохой идеей

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `"alias"` в конфигурацию `nginx` для указания явного пути к статическим файлам:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /root/mysite/myprojectdir/static/;
}
```

Comment: Ошибку 403 это не исправит

Comment: Пробовал не помогло, правильно я понимаю нужно дать доступ к директории static?

Comment: Возможно проблема с правами доступа к директории со статическими файлами? Ещё можно проверить настройки в settings.py и в urls.py